# Guaranty the uniqueness of URL schemes (CFBundleURLSchemes) entries for iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, url, ios

I'd like to know if (and how) Apple guaranty the uniqueness of CFBundleURLSchemes entries for iPhone applications.

In the Apple documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html) section "Implementing custom URL Schemes") they say that about CFBundleURLName "To ensure uniqueness, it is recommended that you specify a reverse-DNS style of identifier", but nothing about CFBundleURLScheme. And when an application launches another application using an URL scheme, there is no reference to BundleURLName, it just refer to URL scheme. (method "- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url" of UIApplication).

So if I publish an application responding to a particular URL scheme on the app store, can I be sure that no other application responds to this URL scheme ? Is it a part of the Apple validation process ?

I have not be able to find any documentation about that neither on the Apple site nor on any other site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as far as I know uniqueness of application URL schemes is not guaranteed by Apple - it only provides a recommendation that can significantly improve chances for that. If everyone will use recommended reverse dns style for their custom urls then they will not "collide" (assuming that company and application name combinations used for url are unique)

Comment: It seems you're right. https://devforums.apple.com/message/244983 and 
https://devforums.apple.com/message/145601

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. In particular, only the scheme is specified as part of the link. The 'url name' is supposed to be reverse DNS, but that is not used in the link so its useless in helping determine uniqueness. Any two custom URL schemes regardless of the 'url name' that have the same scheme name will collide.

Comment: David is correct. Our app follows the reverse DNS rules but it doesn't help at all – there is another app on the store (released after ours) that uses the same URL name and "takes over" the launching of our app. Apple should enforce at app submission time uniqueness, but they don't.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Apple does not ensure uniqueness of the URL scheme and the 'URL name' is nice for documentation but does not factor in when determining uniqueness. Only the URL scheme matters.